# How do I mod rewrite an entire site excluding a couple of subdirectories?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've got a small problem. I've got a good setup which mod rewrites all requests to the site - the only thing is it also rewrites directories which I don't want to be included.

I'm using this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2&split=$3 [L]
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to exclude two directories - access/ and edit/ - edit/ also needs to have it's own set of rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

I can get around this problem by linking directly to the .php file in either directory, but this isn't ideal.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Use [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(access|edit)/
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [L]
...
```

(This is untested, but it should be close)

Comment: Yeah, it should be close. And then add a RewriteCond for the edit subdir too.

Comment: No dice. I think the server ignores the condition and goes straight to the first rewrite rule. I think it must be to do with how the rewrite rule is written, but my regex is very limited - even doing this was trying to find an appropriate tutorial.

Comment: FWIW I think it should be %{REQUEST_URI} instead of ${REQUEST_URI}

Answer (score 1):

An alternate idea (also untested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/access/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/edit/([^/\.]+)/?$ /edit/index.php?action=$1 [L]
... (other rules)
```

which would save you from having to repeat the `RewriteCond` before every rule.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely more elegant.

Comment: The second line works. But the server is still using the other rules for the edit/ directory.

Comment: Maybe try a less restrictive regular expression?  like  ^/edit/(.*)$

Comment: Still no joy... unfortunately.